# MVC4 don't use master layout on redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller that returns the view using MVC4 however for this specific view I don't want it to use the master layout I have in place. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

put

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
```

on the top of your view file. You can also provide path to any other layout file.

you can also change your return statement in given action to

```
return PartialView();
```

so it will not attempt to wrap result of your action with layout file